# Create a composite primary key in Exposed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am trying to create an `IdTable` which uses a composite primary key. When i try the below i get error `DuplicateColumnException: Duplicate column name "id" in table "MyTable"`. How can I fix?

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.EntityID
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.IdTable
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Column

object MyTable: IdTable<Int>() {
    val username = varchar("username", 64)
    val cat1 = varchar("cat1", 12)

    override val id: Column<EntityID<Int>>
        get() = integer("id").autoIncrement().entityId()

    override val primaryKey: PrimaryKey?
        get() = PrimaryKey(username, cat1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this github [issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/353) currently it is not possible to use a composite `PRIMARY KEY` in an `IdTable`. However you already created a composite `PRIMARY KEY` by passing multiple `Column` instances to the `PrimaryKey` you created.